# Need help escaping from awk quotations in bash script

Tags: bash, awk, watch

I have an alias in my bashrc file that outputs current folder contents and system available storage, updated continuously by the watch function.

```
alias wtch='watch -n 0 -t "du -sch * -B 1000000 2>/dev/null | sort -h && df -h -B 1000000| head -2 | awk '{print \$4}'"'
```

The string worked fine until I put in the awk part. I know I need to escape the single quotation marks, while still staying in the double quotation marks and the $4 but I haven't been able to get it to work. What am I doing wrong?

This is the error I get

```
-bash: alias: $4}": not found
```

Answer (score 4):

Since the quoting for the alias is making it tough, you could just make it a function instead:

```
wtch() {
    watch -n 0 -t "du -sch * -B 1000000 2>/dev/null | sort -h && df -h -B 1000000| head -2 | awk '{print $4}'"
}
```

This is a lot like issue 2 in the [BashFAQ/050](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050)

Also, a minor thing but you can skip the `head` process at the end and just have `awk` do it, even exiting after the second row like

```
wtch() {
    watch -n 0 -t "du -sch * -B 1000000 2>/dev/null | sort -h && df -h -B 1000000| awk '{print $4} NR >= 3 {exit}'"
}
```

Comment: @EdMorton Thanks again Ed! I have adopted your suggestion (mostly) as usual

Answer (score 2):

In this case you can use `cut` instead of `awk`. And you'll have the same effect.

```
alias wtch="watch -n 0 -t 'du -sch * -B 1000000 2>/dev/null | sort -h && df -h -B 1000000| head -2 | cut -d\  -f4'"
```

Explaining `cut`:

```
-d option defines a delimiter
-d\  means that my delimiter is space
-f selects a column
-f4 gives you the fourth column
```